# Solution for showing a specific start and end time of a long video file. using react js or node js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Imagine this scenario:
There is a blank page with only two input fields that users can input timestamps like this:

```
start: 00:20:21.330 
end: 00:22:31.330
```

There is also a start button, and when the user clicks it, a video that has now been trimmed based on the input values appears.
the original video file length is 2 hours or so, but the user just wants to see their selected time frame.

I googled and suppose the crop process should be done with node js and FFmpeg library but Is this a rational and optimal solution?? I assume it takes a very long time to shorten, store, and then play a video.
is there any better idea?

Comment: Please check this: https://video-react.js.org/components/player/

Comment: Didn't find anything useful bro

Answer (score 0):

fluent-ffmpeg seems to be the way to go to accomplish this. Currently working through a very similar problem but a lot of researching the topic for doing this in React or Javascript in general seem to point to this library https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg